# Can a span tag be an 'Style' + 'Class' at the same time

Tags: html

Is this 'correct'?

I'm not sure if it should be one of the other? The reason for the class in this span is to call some Javascript...

```
<span style="padding-left: 36px;padding-top:6px;color:#333333;" class="location">
```

Thanks!

- There are no CSS Classes for 'location' it is only there to help the Javascript...

Comment: What do you mean by allowed? It will certainly work.

Comment: I edited my question. Yes, it works but I just wondered if this was 'correct'

Comment: @henry : What are the styles added to the class `location`?

Comment: Same question applies: what do you mean by correct? I would recommend against inline styling elements (define your styles in CSS), but declaring a class for a span element is totally fine when necessary. If you can access the same span element through its parent element I would recommend that, but sometimes you can't. When worrying if something is correct, you should really be asking "How easy is it to read?" and "How easy is it to change?"

Comment: @wanderer - i edited the question - there are no CSS Classes - I guess I should remove the inline CSS....

Comment: Yes, both attributes can be exist at the same tag. You can use class attribute value as DOM reference to JS besides of `id` attribute without declaring CSS class based on its value, but inline CSS styles should be avoided for brevity.